# Uso de "attach" en español en el contexto de depuración de procesos

Tags: verbos, solicitud-de-término, españa, vocabulario-técnico, informática

En mi puesto de trabajo actual, la forma de trabajar difiere bastante de lo que había experimentado hasta ahora. Una de las cosas que estoy aprendiendo es a depurar procesos usando GDB en Linux con la consola de comandos. Nada de depurar paso a paso en una ventana gráfica donde ves con una flechita por qué línea vas. No. Aquí con el GDB se arrancan los procesos o... te *atacheas* a ellos si ya se están ejecutando.

Aquí se usa mucho, como habéis visto, el verbo *atachearse*. Así, en forma pronominal. Tú te *atacheas* a un proceso. El otro día comprobé tal cosa *atacheándome* al proceso. La expresión original es el inglés "to [attach](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/attach) to a process", pero no consigo averiguar ahora mismo cuál sería la expresión correcta en español para este concepto. ¿Unirse a un proceso? ¿Adjuntarse a un proceso?

¿Qué verbo se está usando en la literatura en español para referirse a esta acción?

Comment: No me acaba de quedar claro el proceso: ¿abres una consola, ejecutas un comando y vas viendo línea a línea variables y cosas así?

Comment: @fedorqui no he tenido apenas ocasión de trastear con el [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/), pero básicamente es la forma en línea de comandos de hacer depuración paso a paso. Puedes arrancar un proceso y te aparece una pequeña consola donde puedes escribir órdenes que hacen que el programa se ejecute, inserte puntos de ruptura, pase a la siguiente línea, muestre valores de variables, etc. Pero todo a mano y en una consola de texto, claro.

Comment: Ajá, así si lo entiendo bien cuando te _atacheas_ es como si te pusieras dentro del proceso para mirar qué está haciendo, independientemente de dónde está en ese momento. ¿Como subirse a bordo de un proceso ya lanzado?

Comment: @fedorqui exacto. Te pones a depurar un proceso que ya estaba en ejecución previamente. Como tú dices, "te subes en marcha".

Comment: Yo usaría "acoplar".

Comment: *vincular* / *enganchar* serían las palabras que usaría para ese contexto (**attach** es uno de los tantos vocablos del inglés que se usan en la industria del software). En mi opinión son diversos los factores que previenen (e incluso penalizan) el uso de palabras de otros idiomas, pero uno sin dudas es que la mayoría de la documentación existente está disponible primero en inglés (muchas veces sólo en inglés). Válido decir además que **attach by process id** es una acción común en el desarrollo de software para depurar procesos.

Comment: The word is also used in slightly different contexts in computing. For instance in R you can attach a data-frame, make it available for use in the current environment.

Answer (score 1):

Yo no uso Linux ni entiendo de esas cosas, pero tengo programas de otra índole donde el flujo del tiempo avanza y tú puedes quedarte en un sitio o seguir la pista de algo (en inglés *to track something*).

La palabra que usan en español es **seguir**. Si el resto es lo que se mueve, puedes **anclar** el proceso, mientras que si eres tú el que se mueve, dirías **seguir** al proceso.

También puedes usar sinónimos que se adecuen a este significado, como "rastrear", "rondar", "vigilar", "fiscalizar", "perseguir", "supervisar"... La riqueza del castellano es enorme.

Comment: Esta es la traducción de DEBUG pero no la de ATTACH. Lo que describe Carlos es el proceso de **conectar** la herramienta de debug al proceso para ahí sí hacer "seguimiento".

Comment: Vaya pues no había entendido nada entonces. ¿O sea que un símil sería como subirse a un taxi, y desde ahí decir el típico "siga a ese vehículo?

Comment: Exacto. Y la palabra que busca Carlos es la que describe el acto de "subirse al taxi"

Comment: Ah que bien, de acuerdo. Hmmm, en ese caso, propondría seguir con el símil y decir "subir", "montar", o "embarcar", porque "cabalgar" creo que ya se va un poco jeje.

Comment: @FGSUZ - Parece que es como decirle a una pulga que se suba al perro y que empiece a chuparse la sangre.

Answer (score 1):

**Attach** para todo lo relacionado a informatica es "**adjuntar**"

Archivos, procesos, Actividades, Pasos.

**Track** y **attach** no son lo mismo, **Track** es **Rastrear** y definitivamente eso no es lo que estas haciendo

En cuanto a lo que se usa en la "literatura" si yo fuera traductor me quedaria con la traduccion original para evitar problemas de contexto.

Answer (score 1):

Yo no conocía el término ni el concepto, y no entendí tu explicación muy bien, pero resulta que en Stack Overflow [alguien pidió una explicación del concepto](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6917636/445686).  He aquí algunas partecitas de respuestas que me ayudaron a entender este uso de "attach":

> 1. When you Attach to a Process, you're causing the debugger to attach to the process and allow you to set breakpoints within code that you have not started from a debugger.
> 2. Instead of pressing F5 to start an instance of your app (or pressing the green "go" button), you can attach the debugger to an already running program.
>
>    You can attach the debugger to a running process and start debugging it where it's at. Mostly useful only if you have the debugging information for the executable.
> 3. I tend to use it if my program hits an exception and I'm not already debugging it. I can attach and then view the variables and call stack.

Lo que capté: Mi propia experiencia con los debuggers es que cuando mi programa no se porta como yo esperaba, mato el proceso y empiezo de nuevo, pero a través del debugger.  Pero con este truco de "attachment", entendí que se puede pedir actividades del debugger sin comenzar de nuevo, es decir, cuando el programa ya está en medio camino.  También entendí que este truco es útil para los programas secundarios que uno no echa a andar directamente.  (Perdón, no conozco la terminología de la computación en español, como por ejemplo "debugger".)

En base a esto, propongo:

> **insertar, insertarse**
>
> *I can attach and then view the variables* | Puedo insertarme [al programa] y luego ver los valores de las variables.
>
> *You can attach the debugger to an already running program* | Puedes insertar el debugger a un programa que ya está en ejecución.

Hay una definición de DRAE que apoya esta idea:

> 3. [**insertar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LkUR02C) prnl. Biol. Dicho de un órgano: Introducirse más o menos profundamente entre las partes de otro, o adherirse a su superficie.

(Perdón, no sé qué verbo esté ya establecido para expresar esto.)

Comment: _no conozco la terminología de la computación en español, como por ejemplo "debugger"_ → en general usamos _debugar_

Comment: @fedorqui - Para el sustantivo?

Comment: No, para el verbo. Raramente usamos el sustantivo, pero en ese caso sí usamos lo que mencionas: _debugger_. Pero vaya, lo hacemos con un acento que haría espantarse a cualquier inglés nativo :D

Comment: @fedorqui - Y ni es una palabra bonita en ingles....  Lo busqué en francés ahora y encontré *débogueur* que no esta tan mal.  Hay que inventar algo mejor que *debugger*....